# mutate array in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class example
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] MyArray = new int[10];
        MyArray[1] = 5;
        int[] NewArray = MyArray;
        NewArray[1] = 10;    
        System.out.println(MyArray[1]);
    }
}
```

Why does the system print out `10` instead of `5`?

It seems like whatever changes we made to element in `NewArray`, `MyArray` will change along, why?

I copy this pattern to initiate like int, string variables but they don't behave like this above, why? thanks guy, I am new to CS programming.

Comment: By 'int[] NewArray = MyArray;' you are assigning the MyArray reference to NewArray. This way , both are pointing to the same object.

Comment: Strings are immutable in Java

Comment: @happytimeharry this guys doesn't have any string in his code.

Comment: @SJD But he asked in his question why doing something similar to this with `String`s instead of arrays has different behavior

Comment: @SJD that was how i interpreted the first sentence of the last paragraph of OP's question... plus i like to throw random meaningless comments in for fun ;-)

Comment: Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.

Answer (score 8):

> It seems like whatever changes we made to element in NewArray, MyArray will change along, why?

You aren't changing `NewArray`. You're changing the array that the value of `NewArray` refers to. It's like this:

- `NewArray` is a variable (an unconventionally named one, but hey)
- The value of `NewArray` is a reference
- The reference *refers to* an object

It's really, really important to differentiate between variables, references and objects. Don't feel worried that it didn't just come to you immediately - this is a stage a lot of people go through when they first encounter a language like Java.

The values of `MyArray` and `NewArray` both refer to the same array, so if you make changes to the array *via* one variable, you still see the change when you then look at the array *via* a different variable.

> I copy this pattern to initiate like int, string variables but they don't behave like this above, why? thanks guy, I am new to CS programming.

For `int`, that's a value type - the value of an `int` variable is the number itself, not a reference to an object.

For `String`, I suspect you were changing the value of the variable to refer to a different `String` object - *not* changing the contents of the `String` object itself (which you can't - strings are immutable in Java). For example:

```
String x = "first";
String y = x;
x = "second"; // This doesn't change the value of `y`
```

I like to think of variables as pieces of paper. For value type variables, the value is just written on the piece of paper:

```
int i = 10;
```

is like having a piece of paper with the name `i`, and a value of 10 on it.

For classes and arrays (which are *reference types*) the value on the piece of paper isn't the object - it's a way of navigating to the object. A bit like having someone's home address written on a piece of paper.

Suppose you have two pieces of paper with the same address written on them. If you rub one of them out and write a different address, that doesn't change anything about what will happen if someone looks at the *other* piece of paper and goes to that house. That's like the `String` example above.

The array example, however, is more like this: I write my home address on two pieces of paper, and give them to Fred and Ginger. Fred reads the address, visits my home, and paints the front door red. (He's modifying the *object* - my house - without changing his piece of paper at all.) Now if Ginger reads the address on *his* piece of paper and visits my home, he'll see a red front door.

Comment: See the views skyrocket... Are you going for a reversal badge?

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is because when you say `int[] NewArray = MyArray;` this is copying the *reference* of `MyArray` to `NewArray`.

This reason you are copying the *reference* is because you do *not* call the `new` operator to instantiate a new array.

So, when you say `NewArray[x]` it is pointing to the `x` position in memory of `MyArray` (and hence the value in memory of `MyArray`). No new memory is allocated when you do `int[] NewArray = MyArray;` since the `new` operator is not called.

Answer (score 1):

It is beacuse when you do =, this makes the new obkect to point to the old one. So any changes made to the new one will reflect in the old one to, as they are the same technically.
You should array.clone to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

You are not copying it's value. You say:

Java create "MyArray".
*Java creates a variable poiting at an object*

Java create another array "NewArray" that is the same as MyArray

*Java creates a variable poiting at the same object as MyArray*

Java change the value of NewArray[1] to 10

*Java changes the value on the object it is poiting at, not the variable itself.*

Hope you get it.
As a side note, you should use [0] instead of [1]. Arrays start at 0, like everything in programming. So, the array with 10 items you created starts at 0 and ends at 9. Take note of that.